# Optimizing a recurrence relation for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, numerical-optimization

Given the sequence $$a_k=\frac{(2k)!}{4^k(k!)^2(2k+1)}(0.5)^{2k+1},$$ I should find a recurrence relation for it. I came up with $a_0 = 0.5$ and $$a_{k+1}=\frac{(2k+1)^2}{8(k+1)(2k+3)}a_k.$$ is there an optimized version of this recurrence relation?